# react js unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am a new one who is learning react, i am also not familiar with JavaScript. This is the 1 week that i am trying to import react. I added CDN script tag into my index.html at last.

normally i can add xml tag into js files, but when i try to create component, system returns error.

can anyone explain me what is my mistake?

here is the  index.html and my code.

[image: index.html]

[image: app.js]

[image: error]

I have no idea what is going on when i try to write React.blabla, how system finds React components and how system imports it. i am familiar to Java. thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please edit your post and include your code instead of images ?

Comment: Using create-react-app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) ?

Answer (score 0):

in line 14, {} is an object. A property in an object has a name an a value:

```
{name: value}
```

However, your object has only the value but no name

```
{formatName(user)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = React.createElement(
  'h1',
  {className: 'button'},
  formatName(user)
);
```

See here: https://codesandbox.io/s/myvm10lj5y